# How to do an INSERT statement using JPA Repository

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I know that Jpa Repository provides the save() method in order to persist an object. But I want to do it myself, I am trying to insert something in a table but an error `"could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement"` appear in the POSTMAN response. This is my code

My repository

```
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "insert into TipoAcesso (accesTypeId,accessTypeName,subAcessTypeName,user_id) VALUES (:accesTypeId,Quarto,null,:user_id)",nativeQuery = true)
    @Transactional
    void insertAccesTypeQuartosToUser(@Param("user_id") Long userId);
```

My Controller

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/acessoCozinha")
    public ResponseEntity<Response<TipoAcesso>> insertAccessCozinha(HttpServletRequest request) {

        TipoAcesso tipoAcesso = new TipoAcesso();
        Response<TipoAcesso> response = new Response<>();
        try {  
            tipoAcesso.setUser(userFromRequest(request)); 
            tiposAcessoService.insertAccesTypeCozinhaToUser(tipoAcesso);

        }   catch (Exception e) {
            response.getErrors().add(e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole stack trace? From what I see accesTypeId is not set

Comment: Perhaps "accesTypeId" should be "accessTypeId"?

Comment: Yes, I taken that variable it was not supposed to be there. Still the error ocurrs. My question is,is the sintax of the INSERT INTO statement well?

Comment: Table 'santacasadb.tipoacesso' doesn't exist this error shows up, but the entity exists, should I need to put anything else to the query?

Comment: Add a second parameter in your method  for `:accesTypeId`, eg `void insertAccesTypeQuartosToUser(@Param("user_id") Long userId, @Param("accesTypeId") Long accessTypeId);`.

Just wondering, Is there a specific reason why you have to use native query and not JPQL?